# Aerospike data disappeared

Tags: php, aerospike

after adding a lot of data into my aerospike database, a lot of data disappears.
I have also tried to disable TTL and eviction. But nothing worked.
Currently i am using the default configuration.

```
namespace test {
    replication-factor 2
    memory-size 4G
    default-ttl 30d # 30 days, use 0 to never expire/evict.
    storage-engine memory
}
```

there are 256.408 objects saved (24% memory usage), some minutes later
there are only 133.294 objects (13% memory usage).
13,229 objects expired (seems to be correct)
0 objects evicted

What happend with my data?

```
Admin> asinfo

1 :  node
     BB9E091CB7AC40C
2 :  statistics
     cluster_size=1;cluster_key=DCF17F353E9E73A7;cluster_integrity=true;uptime=545;system_free_mem_pct=79;system_swapping=false;heap_allocated_kbytes=1654377;heap_active_kbytes=1863852;heap_mapped_kbytes=2336768;heap_efficiency_pct=71;objects=133295;sub_objects=0;tombstones=0;tsvc_queue=0;info_queue=0;delete_queue=0;rw_in_progress=0;proxy_in_progress=0;tree_gc_queue=0;client_connections=31;heartbeat_connections=0;fabric_connections=0;heartbeat_received_self=3635;heartbeat_received_foreign=0;reaped_fds=0;info_complete=9935;proxy_retry=0;demarshal_error=0;early_tsvc_client_error=0;early_tsvc_batch_sub_error=0;early_tsvc_udf_sub_error=0;batch_index_initiate=0;batch_index_queue=0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0;batch_index_complete=0;batch_index_error=0;batch_index_timeout=0;batch_index_unused_buffers=0;batch_index_huge_buffers=0;batch_index_created_buffers=0;batch_index_destroyed_buffers=0;batch_initiate=0;batch_queue=0;batch_error=0;batch_timeout=0;scans_active=0;query_short_running=0;query_long_running=0;sindex_ucgarbage_found=0;sindex_gc_locktimedout=0;sindex_gc_inactivity_dur=0;sindex_gc_activity_dur=0;sindex_gc_list_creation_time=0;sindex_gc_list_deletion_time=0;sindex_gc_objects_validated=0;sindex_gc_garbage_found=0;sindex_gc_garbage_cleaned=0;paxos_principal=BB9E091CB7AC40C;migrate_allowed=true;migrate_partitions_remaining=0;fabric_bulk_send_rate=0;fabric_bulk_recv_rate=0;fabric_ctrl_send_rate=0;fabric_ctrl_recv_rate=0;fabric_meta_send_rate=0;fabric_meta_recv_rate=0;fabric_rw_send_rate=0;fabric_rw_recv_rate=0
3 :  features
     peers;cdt-list;cdt-map;pipelining;geo;float;batch-index;replicas-all;replicas-master;replicas-prole;udf
4 :  cluster-generation
     0
5 :  partition-generation
     1
6 :  build_time
     Wed Feb 15 21:57:43 UTC 2017
7 :  edition
     Aerospike Community Edition
8 :  version
     Aerospike Community Edition build 3.11.1.1
9 :  build
     3.11.1.1
10 :  services

11 :  services-alumni

12 :  build_os
     debian8

Admin> info namespace
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Namespace Information~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Namespace                Node   Avail%   Evictions                 Master                Replica     Repl     Stop     Pending       Disk    Disk     HWM          Mem     Mem    HWM      Stop
        .                   .        .           .   (Objects,Tombstones)   (Objects,Tombstones)   Factor   Writes    Migrates       Used   Used%   Disk%         Used   Used%   Mem%   Writes%
        .                   .        .           .                      .                      .        .        .   (tx%,rx%)          .       .       .            .       .      .         .
test        development1:3000   N/E        0.000     (256.408 K,0.000  )    (0.000  ,0.000  )      1        false    (0,0)            N/E   N/E     50      971.808 MB   24      60     90
test                                       0.000     (256.408 K,0.000  )    (0.000  ,0.000  )                        (0,0)       0.000 B                    971.808 MB
Number of rows: 2

Admin> info namespace
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Namespace Information~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Namespace                Node   Avail%   Evictions                 Master                Replica     Repl     Stop     Pending       Disk    Disk     HWM          Mem     Mem    HWM      Stop
        .                   .        .           .   (Objects,Tombstones)   (Objects,Tombstones)   Factor   Writes    Migrates       Used   Used%   Disk%         Used   Used%   Mem%   Writes%
        .                   .        .           .                      .                      .        .        .   (tx%,rx%)          .       .       .            .       .      .         .
test        development1:3000   N/E        0.000     (133.294 K,0.000  )    (0.000  ,0.000  )      1        false    (0,0)            N/E   N/E     50      506.382 MB   13      60     90
test                                       0.000     (133.294 K,0.000  )    (0.000  ,0.000  )                        (0,0)       0.000 B                    506.382 MB
Number of rows: 2
```

Comment: Can you give full stats of the namespace. Command : asinfo -v "namespace/test"

Comment: @DerCoder also posted this at: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/aerospike-data-expire/3329/6  ,  says resolved, issue was with his code, Aerospike works fine.

Comment: @DerCoder, mind sharing what ended up being the issue? https://m.xkcd.com/979/

Answer (score 1):

1 - How are you inserting the objects? Are you modifying the default TTL when you are inserting objects? With 30d default ttl, you should not be expiring objects, (assuming you ran info command fairly quickly between 256K objects dropping to 133K). What is the size of your objects?

2 - can you `$grep thr_nsup /var/log/aerospike/aerospike.log` and post output?

3 - can you post output of `$asinfo -v "namespace/test"`

Answer (score 1):

Thx for your help. I found the issue in my code. Aerospike is working fine.
Sorry for this "wrong" alert :D